# Which executive function assessment has the most cognitive models?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, cognitive-modeling

Wikipedia has a [handy list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executive_functions#Assessment) of assessments of executive functions. I recognize a few of them (Tower of Hanoi, Wisconsin Card Sorting), however, what is the most modeled task and what reasons do researchers give for focusing on this task?